# IE8 - background not appearing right with background position and float attributes

Tags: css

May be I am doing something elementary wrong, but things seem to be OK with Chrome/FF but breaks with IE8 (I have not tried on other versions).

I have background set for the body tag with a background position defined.  This is how the html looks.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<style>
body {
    background:#fff url(skyhouse.jpg);
    background-position: bottom left;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width: 100%;float: left;">
    <div style="background-color: yellow;height: 400px;width: 400px;">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I have a div tag immediately following the body tag and one that is floated (left or right), I see that the background is NOT rendered right.

[Div floated left, width 100%](http://masterdb.in/test/t1.html)

[Div floated left, width 80%](http://masterdb.in/test/t0.html)

When I remove the float  or set the margin to auto, background renders OK

[Float removed](http://masterdb.in/test/t2.html)

If I remove the background positioning, the background renders fine regardless of floats

[background position removed](http://masterdb.in/test/t3.html)

Not sure what seems to be the problem.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that.  I have given the entire HTML and CSS in my post.

Comment: OK, try using `background-size: 100%;` in your CSS... It may fix your bug...

Answer (score 0):

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/aHkJ5/1/

It works with this -

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
body {
    background:#fff url(http://www.makems.com/graphic/rainbow-abstract.jpg);
    background-position: left bottom;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}​
```

Comment: That seems to improve the IE8 issue, but does not appear to solve it.  It also appear to break in chrome.  Please see

Comment: Please see masterdb.in/test/t4.html

Comment: I checked http://www.masterdb.in/test/t4.html in chrome and FF. If you are talking about the horizontal scroll, just add margin: 0; to the body, html and it will solve the problem.

Comment: I had increased the div height to 800px. The background position does not appear to work even with margin set to 0 for html and body.  I am running Chrome 19.0.1xxx

Comment: You have set 'background-repeat: repeat-x;' have you checked that? If you want the background to repeat overall the page then use 'background-repeat: repeat;' remove the x

Comment: yes.  In any case I need the repeat-x and background positioned at the bottom.  As I have said in my post, if I remove the float from the div everything works fine in IE8.  Chrome/FF are fine with the float. I was just curious why is that.